# Angular binding to function results

Tags: angular, watch, angularjs-digest

I've been going through the guide on angular.io and came across [the section 
on the NgClass directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html). 
In the example provided the ngClass' source is a component function:

```ts
// HTML
<div [ngClass]="setClasses()">This div is saveable and special</div>

// Controller
setClasses() {
  let classes =  {
    saveable: this.canSave,      // true
    modified: !this.isUnchanged, // false
    special: this.isSpecial,     // true
  };
  return classes;
}
```

Does this not create a large overhead during the digest cycle considering 
the directive does not know when the result of the function has changed and 
would trigger a new evaluation of the function during each digest cycle? In 
contrast I'd expect the following code to provide the same functionality 
but to only re-evaluate specifically when one of the observed values have 
changed (canSave, isUnchanged, isSpecial).

```ts
<div [ngClass]="{ saveable : canSave, modified : !isUnchanged, special: isSpecial }">This div is saveable and special</div>
```

Could someone shed some light on what I should take into account to 
optimize performance? An example use case would be to have this ngClass on 
an ngRepeat that creates ~200 elements on the visible page.

As a side node and smaller question I was wondering if there is any good 
resource to learn about one-time binding (in angular2 vs angular1). The 
guide does not appear to cover this and I was hoping to have an async one 
time bind available in angular2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this not create a large overhead during the digest cycle considering the directive does not know when the result of the function has changed and would trigger a new evaluation of the function during each digest cycle? In contrast I'd expect the following code to provide the same functionality but to only re-evaluate specifically when one of the observed values have changed (canSave, isUnchanged, isSpecial).

Your conclusion is correct.

The `setClasses` method returns a different instance for each call, which makes comparison in `ngClass` more expensive. If the same instance is returned as long as no dependency changed, then binding to a method this
way is fine.

This was addressed recently very. https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3072

> As a side node and smaller question I was wondering if there is any good resource to learn about one-time binding (in angular2 vs angular1). The guide does not appear to cover this and I was hoping to have an async one time bind available in angular2.

Angular2 doesn't support one-time binding.

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the clarification! I ran into this last week but didn't realize it was already adjusted. Previous experience with angular taught me to always take performance into consideration and this would have been a major pitfall.

Comment: Exactly, this is why they changed it.

Comment: Late addition to the answer, but Angular does not have a digest cycle per se. It uses zones for isolated change detection.

Comment: You are right. It should be "change detection" but it's a quote and I assume "digest cycle was just used to make it easier for devs coming from Angular1 to understand what is meant.